# How do I create a folium.chloropleth map without an index error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

I'm attempting to create a chloropleth map using Folium. However, I get an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range when executing

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this error with a wrapper like Folium. If I comment out the data attribute in folium.chloropleth I don't see the error, but of course, then the data isn't introduced and all of my POLYGON shapes are the same color.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[19.433368, -99.137400],zoom_start=9)
type(mexico_city_map)

mexico_city_map.head()

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=mexico_city_map,
    data=mexico_city_map,
    columns=['NumberofTrips'],
    fill_color='BuPu',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=1,
).add_to(m)

m
```

[Head of geodataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQyeM.png)

```
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

IndexError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-11e84157793c> in <module>
     11     fill_color='BuPu',
     12     fill_opacity=0.7,
---> 13     line_opacity=1,
     14 ).add_to(m)
     15 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1061         if hasattr(data, 'set_index'):
   1062             # This is a pd.DataFrame
-> 1063             color_data = data.set_index(columns[0])[columns[1]].to_dict()
   1064         elif hasattr(data, 'to_dict'):
   1065             # This is a pd.Series

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try to place a float in line_opacity so 1.0 instead of 1

Comment: Oh to clarify- the error is thrown on whatever the last line is. It doesn't seem to relate to line_opacity and could just as easily be thrown on fill_color or elsewhere if those last lines are commented out

Comment: `columns=` must be two columns.  From the docs `Must pass column 1 as the key, and column 2 the values.`

Answer (score 3):

Bob Haffner had the correct answer. I needed to pass two arguments to column. The corrected code is below:

```
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=mexico_city_map,
    data=mexico_city_map,
    columns=['Distrito','NumberofTrips'],
    fill_color='BuPu',
    fill_opacity=0.3,
    line_opacity=1.0,
).add_to(m)
```